# Meteor + Autoform: how to show original when doing update with select-multiple dropdown?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to build an update form for a document that has a select-multiple field in the Schema

I use quickForm

I have this on the schema side for the drop down:

```
channels: {
        type: [String],
        label: "Channels",
        optional: false,
        autoform: {
            type: "select-multiple",
            options: function () {
                var dc = Channels.find({}).fetch();
                return dc.map(function (channel) { return {label: channel.name, value: channel._id}});
            }
    }
}
```

on the form side, I pass the doc

```
{{> quickForm
                    collection="Blah"
                    id="updateChannels"
                    type="method-update"
                    meteormethod="updateBlah"
                    doc=this
            }}
```

I get the fields from the document, but the select-multiple shows the list of options, without selected items.

**How do I get the selected items to show selected in that list?**

Comment: Did you check the data saved inside channels fields into database.

Comment: @PankajJatav so, yes it is saved to the DB, but you got me on the right track: I was actually not publishing that field. So THANKS! It works now.